# Vertical Family Tree in CSS3

Tags: css, html-lists

Please find the link below. that's a Vertical family tree script but i need in Horizontal layout.

```
<pre>http://jsfiddle.net/mppjmtja/</pre>
```

this is my sql script

function display_menus($parent_id = 0){

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menus WHERE parent_id = '$parent_id' ");

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){


echo "<div class='tree'>";

echo "<ul>";

while ($row  = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    echo "<li> <a href=''> ". $row['menu_name'] ." </a>";
    display_menus($row['id']);
    echo "</li>";
    }

echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";


}
```

}

display_menus();

Comment: This site is not a "I need something done for me" site.  You must show that you've actually done something to try to accomplish this, as well as show us your actual code, not just link it in a fiddle.

Comment: Maybe you want this - http://codepen.io/P233/pen/Kzbsi

Comment: i tried before this but it's not useful.. i need only two nods per one nod.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can play with the html, and achieve what you want

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #000;
  font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.branch {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
.branch:before {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.entry:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}
.entry:after {
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.entry:first-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:first-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.entry:last-child:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.entry:last-child:after {
  height: 10px;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
}
.entry.sole:before {
  display: none;
}
.entry.sole:after {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><span class="label">Root</span>
  <div class="branch lv1">
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1</span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-1</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-1-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-2</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-2-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-1-3</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry sole"><span class="label">Entry-1-3-1</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-2</span></div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3</span>
      <div class="branch lv2">
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-1</span></div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-2</span></div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3</span>
          <div class="branch lv3">
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-1</span></div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2</span>
              <div class="branch lv4">
                <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2-1</span></div>
                <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-2-2</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-3-3</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-3-4</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-4</span></div>
    <div class="entry"><span class="label">Entry-5</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can produce the same thing  even if the data comes from mysql... Just play with the html.

Comment: please check above my sql script

Comment: This is another question, please create a new question. Hint: change the ul -> branch and li -> entry.

Comment: You can add  tags as desired dynamical using ajax, $.get() or $.post(). which will give same effect as u desired from My Sql. @AneesMughak

Comment: Very Nice code snippet @Luis P. A.  Vertical tree will be much more gr8.